# autoclick on download icon, as soon as page loads

Tags: google-chrome-extension, download, automation, firefox-addon

### My Question:

There are hundreds of unique URLs from where I have to download the zip file after clicking on the download icon. Is there any way to automate this process.

### My process:

1. Open the unique web page URL,
2. Download icons appears.
3. Click on download icon to download the file.
4. Same process for rest of the pages.

### Notes:

1. Each zip file has the different name.
2. Files are hosted in the secured server.
3. No access to directory folder.
4. Download icon position changes on every page.

Any chrome extension or fire fox ad don to solve this repeated task? Appreciate your help.

Comment: I am a little unsure what you mean, are you trying to create an extension that enables the user to download a zip file from a third-party website without constantly being redirected? Or have you created a site that has a download button that replies on third party sites and whenever the user select the download button that you have created it redirects them?

Comment: i just need an extension which automatically downloads the zip file from the web page without manually clicking on the download icon. Is that possible ?

Comment: Do you know the URLs beforehand?  If so, sounds like a job for `curl`.

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic** for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Questions about **general computing hardware and software are off-topic** for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [Super User](http://superuser.com/about).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have download url list, then there are lots of add-ons that will help you download them, like DownThemAll

But if you do not have download url list, you will need to have a custom extension solution. Because, first extension needs to connect your server and retrieve download url before downloading the actual file. There needs to be Regular Expression difficulties which enforces custom extension solution.